# How to post array of objects in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have the following code in my

> new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag puppies_path do %>
        <% @kennel.each do |puppy| %>
            <%= fields_for 'puppies[]', puppy do |p| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= p.label :name %><br>
                    <%= p.text_field :name %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= p.label :breed %><br>
                    <%= p.text_field :breed %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= submit_tag %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

And puppies[] array variable, which is supposed to post array of objects to controller is posting only single object. Please help to post an array to controller. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `@kennel` also an array?

Comment: yes @kennel is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have just found an answer...

> In new.html.erb file

```
    <%= form_tag puppies_path do %>
        <% 2.times do %>
            <%= render 'puppies_group_form' %><br>    
        <% end %>
        <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

> In _puppies_group_form

```
    Name <%= text_field_tag "puppies[][name]" %>
    Breed <%= text_field_tag "puppies[][breed]" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual setup for `fields_for` is something like this.

```
<% @kennel.each do |kennel| %>
  <%= fields_for :puppies, @kennel.puppies do |p| %>
```